# Chrome console returns inconsistent results when logging into YouTube account

Tags: youtube, google-chrome-devtools, selectors-api

Is there a reason why `querySelector` returns the desired element on [this page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28VnfwOWLXo):

```
let el = document.querySelector('#description-inner #tooltip');
console.log(el);

<div id="tooltip" class="hidden style-scope tp-yt-paper-tooltip" style-target="tooltip">50 views • Mar 31, 2023</div>
```

And returns `null` if `querySelector` is applied to the parent element:

```
let e = document.getElementById('above-the-fold');
let el = e.querySelector('#description-inner #tooltip');
console.log(el);

null
```

[image]
[image]

**Update:** When I logged in into my Google account the code returns `null`, when I logged out it returns the element. But the element is always available via `#above-the-fold #description-inner #tooltip` in the Chrome console.

**Update 2:** The Opera browser also returns `null` when logging in. But this only happens with one of my YouTbe channels inside the same Google account. When I switch to another YouTube channel inside the same Google account, the code returns the element correctly.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. What is unclear about the documentation? [`Document.prototype.querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) vs. [`Element.prototype.querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector). A [mre] would help; [edit] your question, please. How are the elements with the IDs `description-inner` and `above-the-fold` positioned relative to each other? Why not simply use `document.querySelector("#tooltip")` or `document.getElementById("tooltip")`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon There are multiple ways that I can select the desired element. My question is why `querySelector` does not work on the parent element.

Comment: When I ran the code which you provided in your second example, I got the element. Worked in other videos too. I'm using MS Edge. https://imgur.com/1vx1kV9

Comment: @EdwinPratt It's weird. I tested in Chrome Version 111.0.5563.147 (Official Build) (64-bit). The screenshot is in the post.

Comment: @Neret, it's really odd... Do you have any other browser installed? Perhaps try other videos or reopen browser/devtools?

Comment: @EdwinPratt Try logging into your Google account. When I logged in the code returns `null`, when I logged out it returns the element.

Comment: I can’t reproduce this in Chrome, while logged in.

Comment: @Neret, I tried logging in and out. Even tried Incognito mode.

Comment: The problem exists only in one of my YouTube channels. In all other YouTube channels, the code returns the correct element. I have no idea what this is about. I have updated the post.

Comment: Strange I'm the first to point out the obvious: IDs are unique. (Or maybe I'm just rephrasing the first comment... anyways) Makes no sense to target an ID element to then query a child ID. What's the reason?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I know that the `id` must be unique, but this is not always the case, for example, try to find `#metadata-line` on the `youtube.com` page. I see 60 elements. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iele.jpg